# catkin: how to set up build dependencies of two packages correctly?

Tags: ros, catkin, package, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dear ROS-community!

I am currently struggeling with the setup of "CMakeLists.txt" and "package.xml" of two selfmade catkin packages. To my eyes it does not seem to be a very complicated situation, but somehow I am not able to make it work...

Here is the situation:
Package A builds a c++ library, Package B uses and links against this library.

From my understanding, the CMakeLists.txt of Package A should therefore look something like this:

CMakeLists.txt Package A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(Package_A)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 roscpp
 rospy
)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include 
LIBRARIES libmylibrary.so 
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy
# DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

Package.xml Package A:

```
<name>Package_A</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The A package</description>
<maintainer email="foo@bar.de">foobar</maintainer>
<license>TODO</license>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
```

So now here comes package B, which needs the library of Package A:

CMakeLists.txt Package B:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(Package_B)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 roscpp
 rospy
 Package_A
)

catkin_package(
# INCLUDE_DIRS include 
# LIBRARIES libmylibrary.so 
CATKIN_DEPENDS Package_A
# DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

Package.xml Package B:

```
<name>Package_B</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The B package</description>
<maintainer email="foo@bar.de">foobar</maintainer>
<license>TODO</license>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>Package_A</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
<run_depend>Package_A</run_depend>
```

In this configuration, it is not possible to run "catkin_make", it will stop with the following error:
Project 'Package_B' tried to find library 'libmylibrary.so'. The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'Package_A'?

Why doesn't catkin see the dependency and build the library first, so that the other package can find it?

My only workaround at the moment is to remove the dependencies, build the library stand-alone, put the dependency back in and then build the rest. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130301/catkin:-how-to-set-up-build-dependencies-of-two-packages-correctly?/) by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-18**:
Is this copy-paste from your actual CMakeLists.txt? Cause there is no add_library() statement in Package_A's CMakeLists.txt, so no library would be ever build?

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on 2014-02-18**:
Yes, it is copy-paste from my CMakeLists, but I think "add_library()" is not necessary. See my solution below, I needed to change the name of the library, so CMake can identify it as a target.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-18**:
add_library is definitely necessary. That is the CMake command to create a library target.

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on 2014-02-18**:
Yeah I see that now, i misunderstood the first comment of gvdhoorn.... Of course add_library() is needed. What I posted is not the complete makefile, just the parts where the catkin dependencies are configured. Building at all was not my problem, but making those packages build together didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Problem can be solved by changing "libmylibrary.so" to "mylibrary" in the following lines of CMakeLists.txt of Package A:

from:

```
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include 
LIBRARIES libmylibrary.so 
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy
# DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

to:

```
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include 
LIBRARIES mylibrary
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy
# DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) with karma: 318 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You first need to use `add_library()` in package A. In package B you will need an `add_executable()`.

After that is done you need to tell CMake about the dependency between both using:

```
add_dependencies(myexecutable ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

Please consider reading the catkin tutorials as well as documentation: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials and http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2